# How can I make an offline png sequence recorder at 60fps?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to capture a sequence of images, 60fps, 4k, of the Unity Camera in non-realtime (offline).

So far I am able to capture each frame successfully, but I can't figure out how to make it offline, and conform to 60fps.

I am capturing the frames like this:

```cs
            // get main camera and manually render scene into rt
            Camera camera = this.GetComponent<Camera>(); // NOTE: added because there was no reference to camera in original script; must add this script to Camera
            camera.targetTexture = renderTexture;
            camera.Render();
            this.lastRenderTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;

            // read pixels will read from the currently active render texture so make our offscreen 
            // render texture active and then read the pixels
            RenderTexture.active = renderTexture;
            screenShot.ReadPixels(rect, 0, 0);

            // reset active camera texture and render texture
            camera.targetTexture = null;
            RenderTexture.active = null;

            // get our unique filename
            string filename = uniqueFilename((int)rect.width, (int)rect.height);

            // pull in our file header/data bytes for the specified image format (has to be done from main thread)
            byte[] fileHeader = null;
            byte[] fileData = null;

 // create new thread to save the image to file (only operation that can be done in background)
            new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
            {
                // create file and write optional header with image bytes
                var f = System.IO.File.Create(filename);
                if (fileHeader != null) f.Write(fileHeader, 0, fileHeader.Length);
                f.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
                f.Close();
                Debug.Log(string.Format("Wrote screenshot {0} of size {1}", filename, fileData.Length));
            }).Start();
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: How would you guarantee that it will run 60FPS on specified machines (especially with 4K graphics)? This is a tricky question because it sounds like you would probably have to run some optimization testing yourself.

Comment: That's the point of it being "offline".   When rendering, Unity will run much slower than 60fps, but the sequence of images will conform to 60fps footage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [time settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TimeManager.html), set all timestep to 1/60 (approx 0.01666667)

Then caputre screen in OnPostRender event.

[image: timesettngs]

Comment: Should I also change the Time Scale?

Also, the OnPostRender function doesn't seem to be getting called  (I attached the containing script to the camera object, so I'm not sure why it's not being called).

Comment: This answer solved my problem.   I changed the Timestep values to 0.01666667.  However I was unable to get the OnPostRender function to be called.  I will look into that separately.

Comment: Not necessary to change time scale, and OnPostRender is called on an enabled camera, if it's not work you can also use WaitForEndOfFrame.